# Display the date in PHP from a datetime field in SQLExpress

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime, strtotime

I have been crawling through the web and trying to find a solution so I am coming here.

I have an MSSQL database and I am using PHP5.3 to connect and fetch data from one of the tables. The issue I am having has to do with dates.

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TAData WHERE DateTime >= '2013-11-11T07:45:00.000'");

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
print_r ($row['DateTime']);
echo "<br />";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['DateTime']));
}
```

With the output looking like this:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2013-11-11 07:46:08 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Africa/Johannesburg ) 

January 1, 1970, 2:00 am
```

All I need is a simple date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) that I can use. Once I have it in any sort of format (or understand how it works), I can manipulate it from there. But it is not displaying in any functional way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access property `date` on DateTime object, like in the other answer:

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->date; # this will trigger Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date
```

Please don't use any `strtotime()` or `date()` functions, when you already have DateTime object! Just use method `format()` on DateTime object to format datetime, like:

```php
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
# or $row['DateTime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); in your example
```

Comment: I modified my code and now I have: echo "<td>" . $row["DateTime"]->format('Y-m-d') . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row["DateTime"]->format('H:i') . "</td>"; which works 100%

Comment: @Demonwolf: cool. There are a lot of other great [DateTime methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) you could learn, for the future ;)